# Two identical network cards, one unclaimed

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, proxmox, lshw

I got two identical network cards in my server that I run Proxmox VE on. One of them is `unclaimed`, the other one is running fine. Can anyone help with this? I understand that `unclaimed` usually is a hint for a missing driver. But why does the second card work? Might this be a hardware failure?

Thanks for any answer!

`lshw -class network` Output:

```
root@pve:~# lshw -class network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:91930000-9193ffff memory:91940000-9194ffff memory:91950000-9195ffff memory:91d40000-91d407ff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 00
       serial: 2c:ea:7f:e0:4a:59
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=6.2.16-3-pve duplex=full firmware=FFV21.60.8 bc 5720-v1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
```

The entire `dmesg` output is available as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/ihrigb/db085235b837c8593f20be2032a10d48) but what I think are the relevant parts (`dmesg | grep tg3`) are here:

```
[    1.076509] tg3 0000:04:00.0: phy probe failed, err -19
[    1.094731] tg3 0000:04:00.0: Problem fetching invariants of chip, aborting
[    1.117495] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95720) rev 5720000] (PCI Express) MAC address 2c:ea:7f:e0:4a:59
[    1.117499] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eth0: attached PHY is 5720C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    1.117500] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[    1.117502] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    1.125569] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth0
[    8.677752] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eno2: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[    8.677755] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eno2: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[    8.677756] tg3 0000:04:00.1 eno2: EEE is disabled
[ 1190.696920]  dm_thin_pool dm_persistent_data dm_bio_prison dm_bufio libcrc32c hid_generic usbmouse usbhid hid xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas intel_lpss_pci crc32_pclmul ahci spi_intel_pci i2c_i801 intel_lpss mpt3sas raid_class spi_intel i2c_smbus idma64 tg3 libahci xhci_hcd scsi_transport_sas video pinctrl_cannonlake wmi
```

Kernel identifies at boot time with this message

```
Linux version 6.2.16-3-pve (tom@sbuild) (gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PVE 6.2.16-3 (2023-06-17T05:58Z) ()
```

`lspci | grep net` Output:

```
root@pve:~# lspci | grep net
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

Comment: It looks like one is the controller and the other is an interface. The other card isn't listed at all. Did the kernel identify both at boot time?

Comment: roaima +1. It looks like you've got just **one**.

Comment: Thanks for checking into this! Maybe I should have been more precise. It seems to be *one* network card with *two* interfaces of which one is not available.

Comment: @roaima how can I check, if the kernel identified both?

Comment: @roaima dmesg is here: https://gist.github.com/ihrigb/db085235b837c8593f20be2032a10d48
I am not familiar with that log, maybe you can help out?

Comment: @roaima, added `lspci | grep net` output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we got it fixed finally. Turned out that somehow the hardware fixed itself after a hard reset and de-energizing. `tg3` is in fact the correct driver, so it works now.
Thanks @roaima for your support!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one is the controller and the other is an interface. The second interface isn't listed at all.

According to a related answer on AskUbuntu, [Broadcom BCM5720 not working in Ubuntu 20.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364016/473234), this is triggered by a driver mismatch, where the system is wrongly using the `tg3` (Tigon) driver.

The solution that answer proposes is to install the `linux-modules-extra` package and use the `bnx2` module instead of the `tg3`.

Once you have `bnx2` it may get loaded automatically in preference to the `tg3` or we may have to blacklist the `tg3` and forcibly load the `bnx2`. At this point, not having a card with which to test, I can't tell.

Comment: I did not manage to install `linux-modules-extra` as I could not find a package, but I found that there are `/lib/firmware/bnx2` and `/lib/firmware/bnx2x` firmwares on the system. Might the idea of blacklisting help?

Comment: Try it by all means